# How to create a file in remote host along with the creation of directory using ssh

Tags: perl, file, ssh, file-handling, net-ssh

I have a file say /a/b/c/file in my host. I want to create a file on remote host in directory say dest. Now the question is, how do I create a file in remote host as /dest/a/b/c/d/file using perl script and using ssh. Any idea how do I create directories in script.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce the directory structure, use `catfile` and `abs2rel` from the [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) module: `catfile` joins pieces to make a path, and `abs2rel` gives the path relative to some base directory.

The [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) module's `copy` will copy to a handle. This fits nicely with how `sshopen3` opens handles to the standard input, output, and error on the destination side.

The remote command has 3 parts:

- `mkdir -p $dst_dir`, creates all directories preceding the file in the destination path
- `cat >$dst_file`, connects the `SEND` handle to the destination file
- `md5sum $dst_file`, shows that the data arrived safely

Sample program below:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Spec::Functions qw/ abs2rel catfile /;
use Net::SSH qw/ sshopen3 /;

my $HOST     = "user\@host.com";
my $SRC_BASE = "/tmp/host";
my $SRC_FILE = "$SRC_BASE/a/b/c/file";
my $DST_BASE = "/tmp/dest";
system("md5sum", $SRC_FILE) == 0 or exit 1;

my $dst_file = catfile $DST_BASE, abs2rel $SRC_FILE, $SRC_BASE;
my $dst_dir  = dirname $dst_file;
sshopen3 $HOST, *SEND, *RECV, *ERRORS,
         "mkdir -p $dst_dir && cat >$dst_file && md5sum $dst_file"
  or die "$0: ssh: $!";

binmode SEND;
copy $SRC_FILE, \*SEND or die  "$0: copy failed: $!";
close SEND             or warn "$0: close: $!";  # later reads hang without this

undef $/;
my $errors = <ERRORS>;
warn $errors if $errors =~ /\S/;
close ERRORS or warn "$0: close: $!";

print <RECV>;
close RECV or warn "$0: close: $!";
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./create-file
746308829575e17c3331bbcb00c0898b  /tmp/host/a/b/c/file
746308829575e17c3331bbcb00c0898b  /tmp/dest/a/b/c/file
```

Comment: Thanks. I could get your code.I am sorry. But I am pretty new to all this file and directory handling.
How do I handle a case wherein, for example.

Say I have host directory /src in variable $src_dir
host directory file ./a/b/f1 in variable $src_file

destination directory /dst in varisble $dst_dir
now I need file like /dst/a/b/c/f1


now 1st problem.. I do $dst_dir/$src_file I get /dst/./a/b/c/f1
where I need get rid of the extra ./ and create directory /dst/a/b/c  by somehow getting directory path from $src_file and create a file f1 under it.

How do I go about this problem. 

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I could get the solution. I used the use File::Basename module as suggested by you to get the fileame and the directory. Then I created the directory in remote host using mkdir -p "dir" using ssh. And then created the file. That worked very well. Thanks much for your help.